# Where is Add Style Rule option in css stylesheet Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015, stylesheet

I am watching asp.net tutorial in **visual studio** but I cannot find [the **Add Style Rule  option**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTCyl.png)
it occurs from right click on **css**
also I cannot *drag and drop* the **stylesheet** on my **html** document.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the CSS style sheet in the editor.
2. In the Styles menu, click Add Style Rule.

The Add Style Rule dialog box is displayed.

Note: *The Styles menu appears when you open an external CSS style sheet for editing. On the Styles menu, the Build Style option becomes available when you put the cursor inside the braces for a style rule.*

3. Select the style options that you want, and then click OK.

The style rule is added to the CSS style sheet.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907572(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Stylesheet Toolbar for VS 2015 was not included. According to Microsoft, they are planning on bringing a more powerful experience back at sometime in the future. That is what I found when I was looking for the same thing.